# how do you Change valuemycollection () function to use higher level functions like reduce and map. or Use lambda function as a function argument,

Tags: python

How do you Change valuemycollection () function to use higher level functions like reduce and map. or Use lambda function as a function argument.

```
from cards import Card
from functools import reduce


myCards = []
def readcardinfo (f):
# read info from file for 1 card (5 lines) and return the Card 
instance to the main program.
# use f.readline to read each attribute value and assign to the 
instance attributes below
       team = f.readline().strip() 
       name = f.readline().strip()
       cardyear = int(f.readline().strip())
       cardcondition = f.readline().strip()
       cardvalue = int(f.readline().strip())
       return Card (team, name,cardyear,cardcondition,cardvalue)
   
class Card:
    def __init__(self, team, name,cardyear,cardcondition,cardvalue):
       self.team = team
       self.name = name
       self.cardyear = cardyear
       self.cardcondition = cardcondition
       self.cardvalue = int (cardvalue)
    def __str__ (self):
       return "{:<20s} {:<15s} {:4d} {:4s}  {:5d}".format(self.team, 
self.name, self.cardint, self.cardcondition, self.cardvalue)
    def __lt__ (self, other):
        return self.cardvalue < other.cardvalue
    def updatevalue (self, newvalue):
        self.cardvalue = newvalue
    def getvalue(self):
        return self.cardvalue      
    
def printmycollection ():
# change to print (c) using __str__ class method
     for c in myCards:
     print(c)
def sortmycollectionbyvalue ():
# define __lt__ class method
    myCards.sort ()
def updatesandykoufaxvalue ():
#define updatevalue () mutator class method and getvalue() extractor 
method
    for i in myCards:
        if i.name == "Sandy Koufax":
            break
   i.updatevalue (i.getvalue() + 1000)
def valuemycollection ():
#change to use reduce () high level function.  
    collvalue = 0
    for i in myCards:
         collvalue += i.getvalue ()      
   return collvalue
def main ():
     f = open ("players.txt", "r")
# append Card instances (5) read from file
     for i in range (5):
       myCards.append (readcardinfo (f))
     f.close ()
     printmycollection ()
     sortmycollectionbyvalue ()   
     print ("I own $%d in baseball cards!" %(valuemycollection ()))
     updatesandykoufaxvalue ()   # increase by $1000
     sortmycollectionbyvalue ()
     printmycollection ()
     print ("I own now $%d in baseball cards!" %(valuemycollection 
      ()))
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main ()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the code as text. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/68587)

Comment: You don't need map function. What do you currently understand (or not) about the reduce function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum  function makes more sense

```
def valuemycollection():
    return sum(i.getvalue() for i in myCards)
```